# PHP - Multiply two arrays but one is the quantity and one is the price

Tags: php

I have a form with two input fields:

Parts Price and
Parts Quantity

And user can click a button to add as many as they want.

I need to calculate the parts * the quantity to get a sum. For example, if the user has Part one which is 10 dollars and has a quantity of 2. The second part is 20 dollars with the quantity of 2, the sum should be 60 dollars.

```
Part 1 * Quantity = sum of part 1
Part 2 * Quantity = sum of part 2
Sum of part 1 + Sum of part 2
```

This is a simple math equation but i get confused when it comes to arrays.

I tried the following but it only works right if the quantity is 1:

```
 $sumofparts = array_sum($_POST['partsprice']) * array_sum($_POST['partsquantity']);
```

When i try the code with a part with the price of 10 dollars and a quantity of 2 and another part is 10 dollars with the quantity of 2 the sum should be 40; however I'm getting a sum of 80

Comment: (10 + 10) * (2 + 2) = 20 * 4 = 80 as expected. PEMDAS. Order of operations. What you want to do is loop over one array and multiply the price by the quantity and then add that to a total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your math is wrong. What you need is to `sum results of multiplying` and not `multiply sums`. In a simple way it can be done like:

```
$sum = 0; 
foreach ($_POST['partsprice'] as $k => $v) {
    $sum += $v * $_POST['partsquantity'][$k];
}
echo $sum;
```

Comment: Prefect: A small security note, if you don't verify the price is correct and trust what the user sends back with the form, they'll be able to set their own prices. That's probably not what you want. So you'll probably want to change POST out for loading the prices from the database.

Comment: @DampeS8N sure it must be checked. But still the question is about flawed math)

Comment: That's why this is a comment. It shouldn't go without saying.